# What is the name of this kind of DC power connection?

Tags: connector

This connector is going to an LED grow light and is the output of the pictured LED Driver.  The output of the driver is 20-30VDC 900mA.

First of all, I didn't know that DC power could even use a third pin?

Second, the cable is too short and I need an extension cable but don't know what to search for and "3-pin DC power cable" turns up nothing useful.

Note too that there's a flat ridge on the top so orientation seems to matter...

[image]

Comment: It is a proprietary connector. There is no standard for DC connectors.

Comment: There is no standard for LED DC connectors. Your best bet it to hope that the company that sells the power supply and/or LEDs also sells an extension cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DC output connectors aren't limited to just two pins, depending on the requirements of the device being powered. A good example is your typical ATX power supply in a computer. There can be several separate voltages (sometimes called *lines* or *rails*) such as +12V, +5V, +3.3V, and so on. In an LED driver application, it is possible that two different voltages are being supplied with a common ground. There can also be conductors used for feedback, regulation, and proprietary usage, such as a laptop that verifies the power supply being used is of the appropriate wattage or brand.

It's also just as possible and likely that the third pin isn't used at all. The manufacturer may have chosen the connector simply to ensure that some other power supply, with a more common connector (such as a barrel jack), isn't used. In constant-current devices, such as LED strips, it's important to use a constant-current supply instead of a switching supply (SMPS).

As Lior stated in his/her answer, it appears to be a proprietary connector. However, you might be able to find something that matches or is close enough with some of the following terms:

- **circular** connector
- **Mini DIN** connector
- **push-pull** *(as opposed to screw, bayonet, and twist — the flat ridge prevents all but push-pull type)*

Note that if you just want to extend the cable, you may find it cheaper, easier, and quicker to cut the cable, insert the desired extra length, solder and heat shrink both ends of the splice. Just ensure that you connect the same conductors together and use the same (or thicker) gauge of wire. Keep in mind that adding a substantial length could cause extra power dissipation.